# PHP replacing blank images with a default one

Tags: php, html

Having one of those brain fade moments this morning. I have the following php:

```
$imgset = $result->fields[6];
if ($imgset = '')
{
    $imgset = 'logo';
}
else
{
     $imgset = $result->fields[6];
}
echo '<img id="imgdisp" src="/img/'.$imgset.'.jpg" />';
$imgset = '';
```

Where it looks to see if the result from the database is blank and if so, should put in logo.jpg instead of whatever the result is. For some reason though, it just does not want to work and I am probably being completely blind, but cannot see why not. I still get blank images in the HTML and filenames of "/img/.jpg" as though $imgset is still passing through a blank. The values are not NULL in the SQL either, they are most definitely blank entries inputted from an inputbox using a _POST in a form elsewhere.

Comment: I would use `if (empty($var))` for checking that value. Plus I would not rely on that value anyway. Simply let PHP check if the image exists on the path you give it to. if not display the fallback image.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. `==` is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
 if ($imgset = '') {
```

Is always setting `$imgset` to empty. Use comparison instead:

```
 if ($imgset == '') {
```

Your else is also not needed since in that case `$imgset` is already set as `$result->fields[6];`.

Comment: Yeah, proper brain fade. Thanks. Will stick this as answer in 4 minutes ;)

Comment: @bmgh1985 Happens to all of us :).

Answer (score 2):

Try to verify if the image exists in your path as well

```
   <?php 
     $imgset = $result->fields[6];
     if ($imgset) {
       $imgset = $result->fields[6];
       $path ='pathtoimages';
       if(!file_exists($path.'/'.$imageset.'.jpg'){
         $imgset = 'logo';
       }
     }
     else
     {
        $imgset = 'logo';
      }
     echo '<img id="imgdisp" src="/img/'.$imgset.'.jpg" />';
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that improvement idea. Had not occurred to me to check the path (although that is because in my case images are previewed before submitting the data originally) but may still prove useful in case images get moved so will probably add this too.

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis here: `$imageset.'.jpg'){` I try to fix it but "Edits must be at least 6 characters;" advise pops again :(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to compare on the if condition and instead you are assigning an empty value to $imgset. `if ($imgset = '')` should be `if ($imgset == '')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$imgset = $result->fields[6];
if ($imgset == '')
{
    $imgset = 'logo';
}

echo '<img id="imgdisp" src="/img/'.$imgset.'.jpg" />';
$imgset = '';
```

you do not need the else part as the value is already assigned in the first statement.

Comment: Thanks. The else part was only added because of my brain fade and it setting them all to '' by having one = instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ternary operator it can be done like this:

```
echo '<img id="imgdisp" src="/img/'.(empty($imgset)?'logo':$imgset).'.jpg" />';
```

Shorter code at the cost of readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why it's better to reverse the condition:

```
if ('' = $imgset)
```

would have lead to an error.

The answer:

```
if ('' == $imgset)
//or
if (empty($imgset))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting from MYSQL, you can use something like

```
SELECT *,COALESCE(image,"logo") AS image FROM ....
```

This way when the results come back and some rows have a NULL image, it will be replaced by "logo" so you don't need the IF logic in your PHP :)